# Passing custom arguments to a slot in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qwidget

I'm having some troubles trying to pass a custom widget to a custom slot inside my Qt App.

Here an example of what I need: (Note the slots)

```
void MainWindow::HttpRequest(const QString & URL, QCustomWidget *Feed) {
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(URL)));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(HttpImageError(Feed)));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(HttpImageFinished(Feed)));
}
```

I've already searched on Google and I've found that `QSignalMapper` is used to pass arguments to slots, but `QSignalMapper` is usable only to pass integers, `QStrings`, `QObjects` and `QWidgets`. I need to pass a custom widget. I've also read that there are tricks to wrap the custom widget inside a struct or something like that, but I'm very confused on how to do that.

Does anybody can help me?

Comment: First your signal must have the same signature as the slot. So if you want an object passed to the slot, that object must come from the signal. However, if you do want to connect a void signal to a non-void slot, the input to which comes from the context, like a member of `this`, there are ways to do it, too. Voting to close this question because it's not clear which one is being asked.

Comment: Can you make an example? ty

Comment: Please help me, if you can write down a simple example based on the first case you've pointed out would be great! :) thanks

Comment: you can safe `Feed` as a member variable, connect `SIGNAL(finished(void))` to a `SLOT(HttpImageFinished(void))`, then in `HttpImageFinished(void)` you call `HttpImageFinished(Feed)` with the saved `Feed`. Either connect `SIGNAL(finished(void))` to `SLOT(HttpImageFinished(void))`, or connect `SIGNAL(finished(QCustomWidget *))` to `SLOT(HttpImageFinished(QCustomWidget *))`. If the signatures doesn't match, you must figure out a way to relay the signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Qt 5 and C++11 you can use a new lambda syntax:

```
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::NetworkError, [this, Feed]() {
    this->HttpImageError(Feed);
});
```

Here an additional `Feed` parameter to the slot function is added to lambda capture block.

Comment: What is the first error? If using GCC, you have to enable C++11 syntax with `-std=c++11` option.

Comment: C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\mainwindow.cpp:116: error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(QNetworkReply*&, const char [36], MainWindow::HttpRequest(const QString&, bool, QCustomWidget *)::<lambda()>)'
         });     I've added the C++11 line in the project file

Comment: I assumed `NetworkError` was the signal function, apparently it is a character string of the QNetworkReply class. Just pass a pointer to the signal function in your second parameter, in your case it is probably `&QNetworkReply::error`.

Comment: Thanks S.T. but I've found a walk around to my problem using a queue!! :)

Comment: Thank you, most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just for further information... 
I found another solution to the problem, in fact to pass a custom widget I've subclassed the QSignalMapper class (I haven't studied OOP at the University yet, so be patient with me! :P), here some code:

QCustomMapper.h

```
#ifndef QCUSTOMMAPPER_H
#define QCUSTOMMAPPER_H

#include <QSignalMapper>
#include <QHash>
#include "customwidget.h"

class QCustomMapper : public QSignalMapper
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QCustomMapper(QObject *parent = 0);
    void setMapping(QObject *sender, CustomWidget *customWidget);
    void removeMappings(QObject *sender);
    QHash<QObject *, CustomWidget *> customHash;

Q_SIGNALS:
    void mapped(CustomWidget *);

public slots:
    void senderDestroyed() {
        removeMappings(sender());
    }
    void map(QObject *sender);
    void map();

};

#endif // QCUSTOMMAPPER_H
```

QCustomMapper.cpp

```
#include "qcustommapper.h"

QCustomMapper::QCustomMapper(QObject *parent) : QSignalMapper(parent) {

}

void QCustomMapper::setMapping(QObject *sender, CustomWidget *customWidget) {
    customHash.insert(sender, customWidget);
    connect(sender, SIGNAL(destroyed()), this, SLOT(senderDestroyed()));

}

void QCustomMapper::removeMappings(QObject *sender) {
    customHash.remove(sender);
}

void QCustomMapper::map(QObject *sender) {
    if (customHash.contains(sender)) {
        emit mapped(customHash.value(sender));
    }
}

void QCustomMapper::map() {
    map(sender());
}
```

NOTE: I don't know if this is an "elegant" method or if the subclassing is done correctly.. (I've done it without the right knoledgments) anyway it's working fine for me! (miracles happen :D)
I hope that this post will help someone that has the same problem!

Bye, Matteo.